# If the editor-in-chief does not consider plagiarism, is there any possibility of resorting to a new assessment in the scientific community?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, thesis, plagiarism

The question is a complement for other post not completely answered yet ([Plagiarism, intimidation and misuse of doctoral theses results in Brazil](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176651/plagiarism-intimidation-and-misuse-of-doctoral-theses-results-in-brazil)):

If the editor-in-chief does not consider plagiarism, is there any possibility of resorting to a new assessment in the scientific community? There any organisation for take a advice?

There is already a set of documents that prove the situation of plagiarism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attempt to overrule the editor-in-chief by contacting the publisher. You will need very strong evidence, but if your complaint is successful, the publisher can fire the editor-in-chief and retract the plagiarized paper(s).

Comment: OP: indeed include any sort of evidence. Copy of your thesis, emails, etc.

Comment: This approach works better if you make a public stink, e.g. by finding a journalist who finds the story interesting.

Comment: Can I send the "suspicious" article of plagiarism to the editor-in-chief with annotations (sticknotes of pdf) for better readability? Will there not be a violation of laws with this? And the emails exchanged with the professor who authored the plagiarisms, could you also send them without problems?

Comment: @user78008 start by telling them there's plagiarism and presenting your evidence. I don't know what's in your emails with the authors, but if they are not directly relevant you could say "I've already tried to notify the authors [but ...]. Emails available if you want to see them." Also, are you trying to convince the editor-in-chief now or the publisher? The question makes it sound like you've already tried to convince the editor-in-chief.

Comment: How I mentioned in the other post, the professor that plagiated has political influence with local government in Brazil. There a afraid because in Brazil there are a high level of corruption, so if a student is too quick to demand a retraction or other of denuntiate, he can do a lot of harm for your life. Sadly, in Brazil even in prestigious universities is commom the academic perseguision and this prevalece above de razonable. There many cases that the occur a inversion of history and the student that even that pay for the process. The protecionism is terrible for here. See in a googled.